# Hadoop 1.0.4 - file permission issue in running map reduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cygwin

I am new to hadoop and need to setup a sandbox environment in windows to showcase to a client. I have followed below mentioned steps

1. Install cygwin on all machines
2. setup ssh
3. install hadoop 1.0.4
4. configure hadoop
5. [Applied patch for hadoop-7682 bug](https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win)

After lot of hit and trial I was successfully able to run all the components (namenode, datanode, tasktracker and jobtracker). But now I am facing problem while running map-reduce jobs and getting permission error on tmp directory. When I run [word count example](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) using following command

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount wcountjob wcountjob/gutenberg-output
```

> 13/03/28 23:43:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201303282342_0001_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED Error
>   initializing attempt_201303282342_0001_m_000003_2:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path:
>   c:\cygwin\usr\local\tmp\taskTracker\uswu50754 to 0700
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:689)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:662)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.createLocalDirs(JobLocalizer.java:144)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.initializeJob(DefaultTaskController.java:182)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1228)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1203)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1118)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2430)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I have tried setting the permissions manually but that also doesn't work. What I understand is that this due to java libraries being used that try to reset the permissions and fail. The permission patch that solved the tasktracker problem doesn't seem to solve this one.

1. **Has anybody found a solution for this?**
2. **Can anybody point me to download location for Hadoop 0.20.2 which seems to be immune
   to this problem?**

Comment: Did you format the name node?

Comment: Yes, I used following command bin/hadoop namnode -format.

Comment: What user are you using when running the job? When changing permissions?  Try running as hdfs user and see if that makes a difference.